# perl net sip difference between 2 request

Tags: perl, sip

I try to register as a TCP uri

```
This is perl 5, version 32, subversion 0 (v5.32.0) built for x86_64-linux
```

and the Net::SIP version is 0.833. I installed Net::DNS, IO::Socket::IP

My code result is

```
Failed with error 110
```

but true error result we need is forbiden 403 like this request

```
04:49:58.4 
SENDING TCP: 
REGISTER sip:mydomain.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.217.142:9565;branch=z9hG4bK-d87543-5a2868164442f415-1--d87543-;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:4789@192.168.217.142:9565;rinstance=0064d302c642b7fa;transport=TCP>
To: <sip:4789@mydomain.com>
From: <sip:4789@mydomain.com>;tag=3761872b
Call-ID: ca410d2c64600730@REVTS1RPUC1UMEVKTjIy
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Expires: 3600
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, NOTIFY, MESSAGE, SUBSCRIBE, INFO
Supported: eventlist
User-Agent: eyeBeam release 3015c stamp 27107
Content-Length: 0
04:49:58.9 Proxy slot #1 () - Failed to register! error-code: 403, msg: 'Forbidden'. Will no longer attempt registration for this SIP proxy target. AOR: '<sip:4789@mydomain.com>', route-to: '<n/a>', firewall-proxy: 'F'
```

the is my code

```
sub register{
my @parms = @_;
my $host  = $parms[0];
my $user  = $parms[1];
my $pass  = $parms[2];

 my $ua = Net::SIP::Simple->new(
  registrar => "sip:".$host.";transport=tcp",
  domain =>  $host,
  from => $user,
  auth => [ $user,$pass ]
)|| return 0;
 


$ua->register();
$err = $ua->error;
print($err."\n");
         
}
```

this is my code result

```
Failed with error 110
```

and this is my code debug

```
1653146165.7895 DEBUG:<52> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::__generic_resolver[1194]: issue lookup for AAAA mydomain.com
1653146165.8015 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::addFD[61]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) added fn=3 rw(0) sock=0.0.0.0:54330
1653146165.8067 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::loop[217]: call cb on fn=3 rw=0 dns
1653146165.8104 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::delFD[80]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) delete fn=3 sock=0.0.0.0:54330
1653146165.8105 DEBUG:<52> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::__generic_resolver[1194]: issue lookup for A mydomain.com
1653146165.8110 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::addFD[61]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) added fn=4 rw(0) sock=0.0.0.0:45563
1653146165.8160 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::loop[217]: call cb on fn=4 rw=0 dns
1653146165.8166 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::delFD[80]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) delete fn=4 sock=0.0.0.0:45563
1653146165.8169 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::loop[191]: stopvar triggered
1653146165.8187 DEBUG:<90> Net::SIP::Leg::new[155]: created socket on my ip address:5060
1653146165.8192 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::addFD[61]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) added fn=3 rw(0) sock=my ip address:5060
1653146165.8207 DEBUG:<10> Net::SIP::Endpoint::new_request[156]: create new request for REGISTER within new call 46e20fc20927856981b2d9d2809b6e72
1653146165.8216 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Endpoint::new_request[164]: request=REGISTER <sip:mydomain.com;transport=tcp> SIP/2.0
1653146165.8216 DEBUG:<50>      Call-id: 46e20fc20927856981b2d9d2809b6e72
1653146165.8216 DEBUG:<50>      Contact: 442 <sip:442@my ip address>
1653146165.8216 DEBUG:<50>      Cseq: 1 REGISTER
1653146165.8216 DEBUG:<50>      Expires: 900
1653146165.8216 DEBUG:<50>      From: 442 <sip:442@mydomain.com>;tag=87b34c36a18c196d16d682d384320153
1653146165.8216 DEBUG:<50>      Max-forwards: 70
1653146165.8216 DEBUG:<50>      To: 442 <sip:442@mydomain.com>
1653146165.8216 DEBUG:<50>      Content-length: 0
1653146165.8216 DEBUG:<50>
1653146165.8216 DEBUG:<50>
1653146165.8224 DEBUG:<52> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::__generic_resolver[1194]: issue lookup for SRV _sip._tcp.mydomain.com
1653146165.8233 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::addFD[61]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) added fn=4 rw(0) sock=0.0.0.0:58713
1653146165.8498 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::loop[217]: call cb on fn=4 rw=0 dns
1653146165.8527 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::delFD[80]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) delete fn=4 sock=0.0.0.0:58713
1653146165.8530 DEBUG:<52> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::__generic_resolver[1194]: issue lookup for A CVCSE01.vnoc1.com
1653146165.8540 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::addFD[61]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) added fn=6 rw(0) sock=0.0.0.0:34089
1653146165.8642 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::loop[217]: call cb on fn=6 rw=0 dns
1653146165.8648 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::delFD[80]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) delete fn=6 sock=0.0.0.0:34089
1653146165.8651 DEBUG:<52> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::__generic_resolver[1194]: issue lookup for AAAA CVCSE01.vnoc1.com
1653146165.8659 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::addFD[61]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) added fn=4 rw(0) sock=0.0.0.0:41079
1653146165.8762 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::loop[217]: call cb on fn=4 rw=0 dns
1653146165.8768 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::delFD[80]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) delete fn=4 sock=0.0.0.0:41079
1653146165.8770 DEBUG:<52> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::__generic_resolver[1194]: issue lookup for A CVCSE02.vnoc1.com
1653146165.8784 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::addFD[61]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) added fn=6 rw(0) sock=0.0.0.0:33256
1653146165.8833 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::loop[217]: call cb on fn=6 rw=0 dns
1653146165.8838 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::delFD[80]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) delete fn=6 sock=0.0.0.0:33256
1653146165.8840 DEBUG:<52> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::__generic_resolver[1194]: issue lookup for AAAA CVCSE02.vnoc1.com
1653146165.8847 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::addFD[61]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) added fn=4 rw(0) sock=0.0.0.0:38371
1653146165.9009 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::loop[217]: call cb on fn=4 rw=0 dns
1653146165.9019 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::delFD[80]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) delete fn=4 sock=0.0.0.0:38371
1653146165.9022 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::__deliver[656]: deliver through leg Net::SIP::Leg tcp:my ip address:5060 @x.x.x.x:5060
1653146165.9032 DEBUG:<2> Net::SIP::Leg::deliver[426]: delivery with tcp from my ip address:5060 to x.x.x.x:5060:
1653146165.9032 DEBUG:<2>       REGISTER <sip:mydomain.com;transport=tcp> SIP/2.0
1653146165.9032 DEBUG:<2>       Via: SIP/2.0/TCP my ip address;branch=z9hG4bKb43052164d463f6853365d275968dd117d857999dbe0f028fc4a2a8ddcb625
1653146165.9032 DEBUG:<2>       Call-id: 46e20fc20927856981b2d9d2809b6e72
1653146165.9032 DEBUG:<2>       Contact: 442 <sip:442@my ip address>
1653146165.9032 DEBUG:<2>       Cseq: 1 REGISTER
1653146165.9032 DEBUG:<2>       Expires: 900
1653146165.9032 DEBUG:<2>       From: 442 <sip:442@mydomain.com>;tag=87b34c36a18c196d16d682d384320153
1653146165.9032 DEBUG:<2>       Max-forwards: 70
1653146165.9032 DEBUG:<2>       To: 442 <sip:442@mydomain.com>
1653146165.9032 DEBUG:<2>       Content-length: 0
1653146165.9032 DEBUG:<2>
1653146165.9032 DEBUG:<2>
1653146165.9033 DEBUG:<40> Net::SIP::SocketPool::sendto[259]: need new tcp socket to 85.133.97.241
1653146165.9040 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::SocketPool::_timeout_sockets[312]: timeout sockets
1653146165.9041 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::SocketPool::_timeout_sockets[330]: timeout sockets - need timer
1653146165.9044 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::addFD[61]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) added fn=6 rw(1) sock=my ip address:40125
1653146166.8210 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::loop[172]: trigger timer(disp_expire) 1653146166.81594 repeat=<undef>
1653146166.8212 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::queue_expire[576]: next expire <undef>
1653146173.9086 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::loop[172]: trigger timer(socketpool-timeout) 1653146173.9008 repeat=8
1653146173.9087 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::SocketPool::_timeout_sockets[312]: timeout sockets
1653146181.9096 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::loop[172]: trigger timer(socketpool-timeout) 1653146181.9008 repeat=8
1653146181.9097 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::SocketPool::_timeout_sockets[312]: timeout sockets
1653146181.9098 DEBUG:<1> Net::SIP::SocketPool::_error[349]: connect timed out
1653146181.9100 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::delFD[80]: Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop=HASH(0x5613ead71018) delete fn=6 sock=my ip address:40125
1653146181.9117 DEBUG:<99> Net::SIP::SocketPool::_timeout_sockets[340]: timer cancel
1653146181.9118 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::Eventloop::loop[191]: stopvar triggered
```

Comment: As I already explained [on your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72318998/perl-netsip-register-sip-request-header): the server you gave as registrar is not reachable and that's why the connection attempt fails. It is very likely that your phone contacts a different server, so please check the configuration of your phone.

Comment: sir i work from vps linux I tried 2 vps from two different companies
Do you think this difference could be the problem?
 Where in the correct request we have  To: <sip:4789@mydomain.com> and in my reuest we have this To: 442 <sip:442@mydomain.com>  isee this  To: 442

Comment: Like I said, my assumption is that the working (403) client simply contacts a different host.  Please check to which system this clients data are actually sent to.

Comment: i found the error point .  in my debug is give me this 1653146165.9022 DEBUG:<50> Net::SIP::Dispatcher::__deliver[656]: deliver through leg Net::SIP::Leg tcp:my ip address:5060 @x.x.x.x:5060 .... this is sip server and it give me a true 403 error of domain . but on script net sip it is translate domain to ip to socket connect other ip that is ip show on i ping domain so we have 2 ip . sip server ip and  ping translate ip . so how i make script connect to leg ip sip server

Comment: so how i can make it loop to check socket for all ips extracted from domain

Comment: @Likely It is not about *"ips extracted from domain"*. The host the working client connects to is explicitly configured at the other client, for example as registrar or SIP proxy. You need to use the same IP as the other client, i.e. `registrar => "sip:same_ip_as_other_client:5060;transport=tcp"`.

Comment: can i send u my function ? and my domain and some ips to check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244927/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-soas-saodo).